# Prove that OLS estimated coefficients are independent from other variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, linear-model, data-generating-process

How to prove that OLS estimators do not depend on other parameters, given the same variables are included in the regression?

I generate some random data for 30 observations and 4 variables $x_1,x_2, x_3, x_4 $, then generate a dependent variable $y$ based on these variables plus an error term:

$ y = \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_3 x_3 + \alpha_4 x_4 + u $

I want to formally prove that, given the same data, regardless of the value of $\alpha_1$, the estimated coefficients, i.e. $\hat{\alpha}_2,\hat{\alpha}_3,\hat{\alpha}_3 $ will be the same.

If the text is not clear, here is an [example in python](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wSIVOfnq0j-mf79qaVy1ohk2lI0HCKpj?usp=sharing).

I know the formula for the estimator is:

$\hat{\beta}_2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i2} (y_i - \bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i2}^2}$

which does not depend on the values of other variables, but I am confused, because from this formula it appears to me that if a don't include other variables in the regression, the estimated coefficient would be the same, which is clearly wrong.

Ps: This is not a homework, but self-study, if there is a problem in posting the solution, please provide me with the intuition on how to start.

Ps2: Apologies for a completely basic question, but I am studying linear regression and trying to understand formally the results.

Comment: Please review your notation. First you say that you generate $x_1,x_2, x_3, x_4 $, but then it is $x_2$ and $\alpha_2$ three times in the equation for $y$. Then it's suddenly also $\hat\alpha_3$ afterwards. This makes it hard to see what your question precisely is.

Comment: What does it mean to be "given the same data" but to vary the value of $\alpha_1$??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In matrix notation you have $Y=X\beta + U$ and OLS provides $$\widehat{\beta} = \left(X'X\right)^{-1}X'Y = \beta + \left(X'X\right)^{-1}X'U. $$ As long as $X$ and $U$ are the same, $\widehat{\beta}-\beta = \left(X'X\right)^{-1}X'U$ will always be the same. Now if you change the value of $\beta_1$, say, then the estimator for other parameters does not change.

Answer (score 2):

You formula for $\beta_2$ is wrong. Suppose you would have two independent variables, then you can see in [this](http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Part3/Reg2.html) link that the estimates $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ depend on both $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Only when the two variables are uncorrelated in your sample data, the estimate $\beta_1$ (for $x_1$) would not change when adding independent $x_2$.

However, in sample data (simulated or real) there will almost always be some correlation, even when in the population (simulated or real) there is NO correlation.

Comment: Could you please check my python example? Data are correlated but the estimate is always the same.. I think I`m not benig able to explain, it is not about depending on x1 and x2, but on the tru values of alpha1 and alpha2

Comment: Never used python, but just saw that you generate the data outside of the loop. If you do that inside the loop, you should get different estimates each iteration.

Comment: Also, print all estimates using  print(round(model.params,9)) instead of only one.